# Is my function Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

So, here's my function

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=1$  for $x \in \mathbb{N}$

$f(x)=2$ for  $x \in (0,1)$

$f(x)=0$  for  anything  else

I tried solving it this way:

$f_k=0$ for   $k \in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N})\ \cup(0,1)$

$f=\sum_{R-N\ \cup(0,1)}f_k = 0 < \infty =>$ f is lebesgue integrable

Can I prove from this point that it's not ( or it is ) Riemann integrable?

Comment: It's not supported on a bounded interval.

Comment: Is $N$ the natural numbers? If so, this function is continuous almost everywhere, which is equivalent to Riemann integrability.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your proof of the Lebesgue integrability of $f$, but it comes pretty directly from the fact that $f = 1_{\mathbb{N}}+2\cdot 1_{(0, 1)}$ is a simple function and is thus Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then function is Lebesgue integrable.

Note that $m(\mathbb{N})=0$ and $$\int f= \int_{\mathbb{N}}f+ \int_{(0,1)}f+ \int_{(-\infty,0]}f+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(n,n+1)}f=0+2+0+0=2$$

$f$ is not Riemman integrable in because Riemman integration makes sence in bounded regions.

But we can say that the improper   integral of $f$ as an extension of the Riemman integral is $2$ (this can be proved  by writing the integral of $f$ over the whole real line as a limit of a sum of integrals in bounded intervals)

Also here is a reference  of extended integrals in unbounded regions(intervals)

http://www.matha.rwth-aachen.de/de/lehre/ws07/calculus/Lecture_12.pdf

Comment: $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $\mathbb R$ because no function is Riemann integrable on an unbounded interval.

Comment: @zhw. in that case i meant improperly Riemman integrable.

Comment: @zhw. .here is a reference http://www.matha.rwth-aachen.de/de/lehre/ws07/calculus/Lecture_12.pdf

Comment: But you are correct..i must clarify that to the O.P

Comment: Maybe my terminology ""improper Riemman integrable'' is not correct or does not make sence so i will edit